# How to save parameters to a table sent by form_with method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this below page showing 3 questions, and I want to store the user input into a table called "user_answers" when submitted.

```
(test_one.html.erb)

<%= form_with(scope: @user_answer, url: answer_one_path, local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>1. <%= @questions.all[0].question %></p>
  <%= form.text_field :answer1 %> --> #I want this input saved in the table.
  <p>2. <%= @questions.all[1].question %></p>
  <%= form.text_field :answer2 %> --> #I want this input saved in the table.
  <p>3. <%= @questions.all[2].question %></p>
  <%= form.text_field :answer3 %> --> #I want this input saved in the table.
  <%= form.submit "Submit!" %>
<% end %>
```

When submitted, it then moves to answer page, and I want it to store :answer1, :answer2, :answer3 into the column "user_answer" in "user_answers" table.

```
(Table "user_answers")

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_answer | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's my controller.

```
(homepage_controller.rb)

def test_one
  @questions = QuestionAnswer.where(grade: 1, test_num: 1)
end

def answer_one
end

private
def all_answers
  params.permit(:answer1, :answer2, :answer3)
end
```

Here's my model.

```
(user_answer.rb)
class UserAnswer < ApplicationRecord
end

(question_answer.rb)
class QuestionAnswer < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here's my routes.rb.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "/answer_one", to: 'homepage#answer_one'
  get "/answer_one", to: 'homepage#answer_one'
  get "/test_one", to: 'homepage#test_one'
```

Here's the table "question_answers".

```
(question_answers table)
*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 1
   question: Color of apple? <-- question
     answer: Red             <-- answer
 created_at: 2021-06-11 14:36:50
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 14:36:50
      grade: 1
   test_num: 1
question_id: 1  <-- because it's question number 1
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         id: 2
   question: Color of banana?  <-- question
     answer: Yellow            <-- answer
 created_at: 2021-06-11 17:12:53
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 17:12:53
      grade: 1
   test_num: 1
question_id: 2  <-- because it's question number 2
*************************** 3. row ***************************
         id: 3
   question: Color of Orange?  <-- question
     answer: Orange            <-- answer
 created_at: 2021-06-15 15:54:18
 updated_at: 2021-06-15 15:54:18
      grade: 1
   test_num: 1
question_id: 3  <-- because it's question number 3
```

For example, if a user wrote "red" for :answer1, "yellow" for :answer2, "orange" for :answer3, I want those inputs to be saved with the question number as below;

```
(table "user_answers")

*************************** 1. row ***************************
         id: 1
 session_id: null
user_answer: red <-- # user input
question_id: 1   <-- # since it was question number 1
 created_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         id: 1
 session_id: null
user_answer: yellow  <-- # user input
question_id: 2       <-- # since it was question number 2
 created_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
*************************** 2. row ***************************
         id: 1
 session_id: null
user_answer: orange  <-- # user input
question_id: 3       <-- # since it was question number 3
 created_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
```

I attempted to include "create" method in the homepage_controller.rb as below, but the data didn't get saved in the user_answers table. What am I doing wrong / what am I not doing enough?

```
  def create
    @user_answer = UserAnswer.create(user_answer: all_answers, question_id: params[:id])
    @user_answer.save
  end
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is NOT intended as a copy-paste solution. Its a nudge in the right direction and covers some pretty advanced topics. If you're new at rails you might want to set this up to just answer one question at a time and circle back later.

The Rails way to handle creating multiple resources in a single request is by using [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). To start off you probally want some real tables for the domain instead of storing a bunch of denormalized strings:

```
# rails g model test title description:text
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions
  has_many :user_tests
  has_many :user_answers, through: :user_tests
end

# rails g model question text:text
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test
end

# rails g model answer text:text
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Then you want a class that "wraps" all the UserAnswers which can be though of as the actual sheet of paper that you fill out when you answer a test:

```
# rails g model user_test user:references test:references
class UserTest < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :title, :description to: :test
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :user_answers
  has_many :questions, through: :test
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_answers

  # creates a user answer for every question in the tests
  def seed!
    test.questions.each do |q|
      user_answers.new(question: q)
    end
  end
end

class UserAnswer < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :text, to: :question
  belongs_to :user_test
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
  has_many :potential_answers, though: :question,
                               source: :answers
end
```

The way that nested attributes works is that when you pass an array of hashes to the special `*_attributes=` setter ActiveRecord will handle building multiple instances of the nested records at once:

```
@user_test = UserTest.new(
   test_id: 1,
   user_answer_attributes: [
     { question_id: 1, answer_id: 2 },
     { question_id: 2, answer_id: 5 },
     { question_id: 2, answer_id: 5 }
  ]
)
```

The RESTful way to model gathering responses to differents test is by creating nested routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :tests do
  resources :user_tests, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

```
class UserTestsController < ApplicationRecord
  before_action :set_test
  before_action :authenticate_user! # assuming you're using Devise

  # GET /tests/:test_id/user_tests/new
  def new
    @user_test = @test.user_tests.new
    @user_test.seed!
  end

  # POST /tests/:test_id/user_tests
  def create
    @user_test = @test.user_tests.new(user_test_params) do |ut|
      ut.user = current_user
    end
    if @user_test.save
      redirect_to '/somewhere', success: 'Thank you for your answers'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_test
    @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
  end

  def user_test_params
    params.require(:user_test)
          .permit(
            user_answer_attributes: [:question_id, :answer_id]
          )
  end
end
```

In the form you use `fields_for` to loop through the assocation and create inputs for each nested record:

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_test) do |form| %>
  <div class="questions">
  <%= form.fields_for(:user_answers) do |user_answer| %>
    <div class="question">
      <%= user_answer.label :answer_id, user_answer.object.text %>
      <%= user_answer.collection_select(
          :answer_id, 
          user_answer.object.potential_answers,
          :id,
          :text
      ) %>
  </fieldset>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Using AJAX to submit the answers one by one is also an alternative.